# Help with following the tutorial

Tags: modeling, vertices

I've been working on a low-poly character model of the Mandalorian from Imphenzia, but I'm having trouble trying to follow him. Right now, I'm trying to move some vertices in the right positions near the armpit of the model's right side, but I don't know which ones I have to move, or where to move them. It's too quick for me to do that.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm working on, particularly the part I'm stuck on...
[image]

Here's where in the video I'm stuck in...
https://youtu.be/szIvkd1NBz4?t=417

And here's the file of the project I'm working on...
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: It looks as if you've got a large number of overlapping vertices, possibly because of hitting extrude more than once before actually moving the geometry. in Edit mode, hit '1' for verts then 'A' to select all and then 'M' > Merge by distance. Watch the centre of the status bar at the bottom of the screen when you merge by distance and you'll probably see that around 36 verts have been merged. Then try again!